# Accessibility services for android in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying for accessibility services for android in react-native,
I checked for different articles but i didn't find any thing regarding Accessibility services in react-native,
I found something on Accessibility in react-native, But i want to allow user to access accessibility services permission as well.
Can any one suggest me that how to move forward to achieve this.
Any help much appreciated.

Here is link which i checked in android 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/developing-android-a11y-service/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure what you want exactly but take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibility.html)

Comment: @pritish this is for accessbility i want like accessibility services. this app used that one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=partners.driver.mystro&hl=en

Comment: Do you mean creating own `accessibility service`? The default services like `TalkBack` can be accessed by setting `accessible={true}` as mentioned in android.

Comment: yes i want to create own accessibility service for my app

Comment: That might not be possible with `react-native` alone since you might need to change the native code for that, different for `ios` and `android` respectively

Answer (score 0):

With React-Native's AccessibilityInfo, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/accessibilityinfo, you can detect if TalkBack is enabled or not.